# Writing the Base Case for a recursive program that prints out all the permutations of a given string in C++

Tags: c++

The function is called as: Perm( "xyz", "abc" );  then it would print:
xyzabc   xyzacb   xyzbac   xyzbca   xyzcab   xyzcba
The xyz is fixed and has all permutations of abc concatenated to it.

I started a for Loop to deal with the general case, and part of the base case but I am having a hard time figuring out where I am going wrong.

```
#include <string>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Perm(string fixedPart, string permPart)
{

    if (permPart.length() == 1) {

        cout << fixedPart << permPart << endl;
    }
    else {
    for (int i = 0; i < permPart.length() - 1; i++) {
          Perm(fixedPart + permPart[i] , 
          permPart.substr(0, i) + permPart.substr(i + 1,permPart.length()-1));
    }
    }
}

int main(){

    // Don't touch main!!!

    string s;

    cout << "Enter a String: ";
    cin >> s;
    cout << s << endl;

    cout << "Perms are: " << endl;
    Perm("xyz", s);

}
```

Comment: What makes you believe something is going wrong? What outcome do you observe, and in what way is it incorrect?

Comment: Get some paper and a pen. For the test case of `permPart` being just two characters,  the minimal base case, write out by hand on paper and pen exactly what your `for` loop does, calculating all expressions by hand, and working out everything that happens there. If you do that, your bug should be very obvious. If you don't want to do that, then learn how to use your debugger, to run your program one line at a time, and inspecting the values of all variables as they change. This is exactly what a debugger is for. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: It's not the base case, by the way...

Comment: Consistent formatting and indentation makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not with base case, Just change the for loop condition to

i < permPart.length()

last character also should be swapped with other characters in the permutation

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been looking at this code for hours writing it out. I just had to change the for loop conditon from " i < permPart.length()-1" to "i < permPartlength()" like you said